# PHP - Query to insert data into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been creating a registration system, and my code will not insert the fields: `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` and `username` into my database, however it will insert the hashed password into my database. I think the problem might have something to do with the for loop, but to me it seems like it should work.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once 'config.php';
        $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username'];
        $escaped_values = [];
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $escaped_values[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['$field']);
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('{$escaped_values["firstname"]}', '{$escaped_values["lastname"]}', '{$escaped_values["email"]}', '{$escaped_values["username"]}', '$hashed_password')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is $escaped_values are populated? what is that result of that array?

Comment: `$_POST['$field']` <-- probably not doing what you're expecting. As a side note, I can't for the life of me work out why this code isn't a syntax error...

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah that would be a pretty weird name for an index...

Comment: You need ot change $_POST['$field'] to $_POST[$field] without the '.  The single quotes make it a literal key.

Comment: Where is the syntax error in your opinion? I cant see it. @JonStirling

Comment: My thoughts is that the for loop will take each value of $fields and create an array which, then would be stored in $escaped_values. But now I'm not sure if that would work as intended

Comment: @Cashbee I was unaware that using `{}` would escape quotes inside of it automagically. So while `$string = "some$test["here"]here"` is a syntax error, `$string = "some{$test["here"]}here";` is not.

Comment: @TessRay97 `mysqli_real_escape_string()` returns a string, not an array. IMO this code will work after OP removes the single quotes in `$_POST['$field']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is in this line:

```
$escaped_values[$field] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['$field']);
```

You should use `$field` in `$_POST[]` the same way you are in `$escaped_values[]`, specifically, removing the single quotes.

Right now that loop is reading $field as a literal string each time it loops through, which most likely doesn't exist, giving you an empty `$escaped_values` array

Comment: To be more precise: use `$POST_[$field]` instead of `$POST_['$field']` - no single quotes!

Comment: Thank you, I've been pulling my hair out over this. I cant believe it was so simple as to removing the quotes :D Thank you all for the help